# sed comment line number x to y from files

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am having a software which when running ../configure is failing due to some checks.

I have find a way to comment out the lines 49725-49735 manually then I can install the software just fine.

I need to edit the configuration file automatically and comment those lines.

Is there anyone who can give me a hint how to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not advisable to edit config files like this (fix the error messages), but you know your situation better than I do.

```
sed '49724,49736 {s/^/#/}' file > newFile && mv newFile file
```

IHTH

Comment: Nothing, its just that `> file && mv ..` is more generic. Not all sed support `-i`. Good luck to all!

Comment: I know but I just want to comment out a check for version which does give me lots of headache cause the tool I am using is a custom built one therefore it's version is not what the software expects.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '49725,49735{s/^/##/}' file
```

replace "##" with your comment code

Comment: you should use `-in`

Answer (score 2):

You may use awk,

```
awk 'NR>49724&&NR<49736{$0="#"$0}1' file
```